# jQuery target and change array key based on input value

Tags: jquery

I have a multi dimensional array.  I want to draw out one of the arrays, by changing its key.  How can I target its key and change its value?

**This is my array:**

```
$myarray=
array(2) {
  ["KeyOne"]=>
  array(6) {
   ["firstvalue"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  ["KeyTwo"]=>
  array(6) {
    ["firstvalue"]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
}
```

I then place this array in a drop down select of a form:

```
<select name="selectYourKey" id="key">
    <option value="keyOne">keyOne</option>
    <option value="keyTwo">keyTwo</option>
</select>

<select name="myarray" >
    <?php
    foreach ($values = $myarray[$arraykey] as $value) {
        var_dump($value);
    } ?>
</select>
```

When a user selects a key from the first input I want it to change the input in the second drop down.

I know how to capture the first select. But I am not sure how to change the key.

This is my jQuery capture:

```
$("select[name='selectYourKey']").on('change', function() {
    var arrayKey = $("select[name='selectYourKey']").find(":selected").text();
});
```

I now want to change the array key in the foreach loop with the arrayKey in the jQuery.

Comment: You cannot do that using jquery because its php(server-code) either use ajax or just hide/show option where key matches .

Comment: @Swati so what if it was Json. Would we be able to do it then?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do.  What does *change the array key* mean?  Are you trying to select an option in the 2nd select based on what is chosen in the first? I used your HTML and JS and set up an example JSFiddle, is that what you need?  https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/jdnfuzsx/

Comment: If you want to literally manipulate the array keys and values, you could create the array in JS with your PHP loop, and then do anything you want with it ... ?